# Installing Eclipse

Tags: windows-xp, eclipse, jdk, jvm

I need to install eclipse to use with PHP, so I downloaded it from eclipse.org, extracted the zip file, and tried to install eclipse. It was throwing an error like

> "JRE or JDK must be available in order to run eclipse. No JVM was found after searching the following locations: D:\documents and settings\user\mydocument\download\eclipse\jre\bin\jawaw.exe in your current path"

I installed JDK on my system and then I tried to install eclipse but it was throwing the same error. How can I get eclipse to install successfully?

Answer (score 1):

http://www.java.com/en/download/

Install that. If it errors wipe out java from your system and try it again.

Answer (score 1):

You need a [JRE](http://www.java.com/en/download/) (runtime environment) for *running* Eclipse. While Eclipse contains its own compiler, negating the need for a JDK (development environment), it's still written in Java and hence requires the JRE.

Answer (score 0):

- Make sure the JAVA_HOME environment variable points to the JRE directory of your preference
- After installing JRE, make sure you have restarted your machine

If both do not work
Try running eclipse with a -vm flag (from command prompt)

```
eclipse -vm D:/../YOUR_JDK_FOLDER/bin/javaw.exe
```

If the last works, you might consider reating a shortcut of eclipse on the desktop (or wherever), right click -> properties, and in the target text box (where you have the path to eclipse.exe), add `-vm D:/../YOUR_JDK_FOLDER/bin/javaw.exe` at the end.